# mySQL C++ connector "Commands out of sync" while calling stored procedure multiple times

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a stored procedure, which inserts one record into a table and returns the last inserted id.
When I call it multiple times in the C++ connector, on the 2nd time, it always fails with "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".
The first insertion is successful and the inserted id can be fetched back.

I have closed and deleted the "sql::ResultSet" object after the first call, but it has no use.
In some other posts, I saw that you need to call statement's "next_result()" before the 2nd call, but in the C++ connector's Statement class, there is no such function.

stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE `insert_into_table`(IN ...)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MyTable (...) VALUES (...);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id;
END
```

C++:

```
sql_query = "call insert_into_table(...);";
{
    auto res = statement->executeQuery(sql_query);
    res->close();
    delete res;
    // the second call always fails 
    res = statement->executeQuery(sql_query);
}
```

Comment: Try calling res->next() after execution

Comment: No doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush the ResultSet before calling executeQuery again, failing which, the command-out-of-sync nightmare may come. Deleting the Resultset will not serve the purpose. In your case since the stored procedure is not returning anything, you can try the following snippet:

```
res = statement->executeQuery(sql_query);
while (res->next())
{       
}
```

Suppose, your stored procedure returned an integer, you could have used like so:

```
res = statement->executeQuery(sql_query);
while (res->next())
{
   return res->getInt(1);       
}
```

Comment: I tried to loop the res to the end, but it still has the problem

Comment: I agree with Frank, this is not the answer. Frank did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I know this may be two years to late, and I'm totally copying someone else answer to another question similar to yours. But it is not selected as "the" answer as it should be. It's like the third one down.

So thank
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1601882/andy-braham

Third or so answer here, please upvote him there if you like my answer.

[Connector/C++ MySQL error code: 2014 , SQLState: HY000 and Commands out of sync error why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826139/connector-c-mysql-error-code-2014-sqlstate-hy000-and-commands-out-of-sync)

I ran into this problem also and took me a little while to figure it out. I had even set the "CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS" and "CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS" with no avail.

What is happening is MySql thinks that there is another result set waiting to be read from the first call to the Query. Then if you try to run another Query, MySql thinks that it still has a ResultSet from last time and sends the "Out of Sync" Error.

This looks like it might be a C++ Connector issue but I have found a workaround and wanted to post it in case anyone else is having this same issue:

```
sql::PreparedStatement *sqlPrepStmt;
sql::ResultSet *sqlResult;
int id;
std::string name;

try {

    //Build the Query String
    sqlStr = "CALL my_routine(?,?)";

    //Get the Result
    sqlPrepStmt = this->sqlConn->prepareStatement(sqlStr);
    sqlPrepStmt->setInt(1, itemID);
    sqlPrepStmt->setInt(2, groupId);
    sqlPrepStmt->executeUpdate();

    sqlResult = sqlPrepStmt->getResultSet();

    //Get the Results
    while (sqlResult->next()) {
        id = sqlResult->getInt("id");
        name = sqlResult->getString("name");
    }

    //Workaround: Makes sure there are no more ResultSets
    while (sqlPrepStmt->getMoreResults()) {
        sqlResult = sqlPrepStmt->getResultSet();
    }

    sqlResult->close();
    sqlPrepStmt->close();

    delete sqlResult;
    delete sqlPrepStmt;
}
catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
    /*** Handle Exception ***/
}
```