# C++ MySQL connector execute stored procedure corrupts connection

Tags: c++, mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-connector

In a MySQL Database I have a stored procedure defined by the following create statement:

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `get_next_ticket_number`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_next_ticket_number`()
BEGIN
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT `number`
FROM ticket
ORDER BY `number` DESC
LIMIT 1)+1, 1) as 'next_number';
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

In a QT C++ application I'm attempting to call that procedure and use the result later:

```
std::unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> pstmt;
std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res;

int next_number = 0;

try
{
    pstmt.reset(dbConnection::getInstance()->getDb()->prepareStatement("CALL get_next_ticket_number();"));
    res.reset(pstmt->executeQuery());

    while(res->next()) {
        next_number = res->getInt("next_number");
    }

    dbConnection::getInstance()->getDb()->commit();    // For good measure...
}
catch (sql::SQLException &e)
{
    // Error logging here
}
```

`getInstance()->getDb()` returns a copy of the MySQL connector connection, which is setup with `setAutoCommit(true)` and works fine for all other select, insert, and update queries.

After successfully calling the procedure, all subsequent queries are failing with `MySQL error code: 2014, SQLState: "HY000"`

Why does this procedure call seem to leave the connection in an occupied state?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826139/connector-c-mysql-error-code-2014-sqlstate-hy000-and-commands-out-of-sync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the call in a do-while fixed the issue:

```
do {
// execute code
} while (stmt->getMoreResults());
```